# surface geometry bisection of angle

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, surfaces

I have a question. How can i show a vector bisect a angle $\omega$ between coordinate curves in a regular surface $S$ ?

The problem: Let $X(u,v)$ a local parametrization of a surface $S$. Show that a vector $\alpha X_{u}+ \beta X_{v}$ bisect a angle between coordinate curves if and only if $\sqrt{G} (\bigl((\alpha E + \beta F)\bigr)$ $=$  $\sqrt{E} (\bigl((\alpha F + \beta G)\bigr)$.

I know that vector $\alpha X_{u} + \beta X_{v}$ belong to $T_{p} S$ and the angle $\omega$ between coordinate curves is:

$cos \omega$ $=$ $\frac{<X_{u},X_{v}>}{\Vert{X_{u}}\Vert \Vert{X_{v}}\Vert}$

but i don't understand how can i show bisection.

Comment: Think back to Euclidean geometry. What does it mean to say the ray $\overrightarrow{OC}$ bisects the angle $\angle AOB$?

Comment: it means the ray divides angle in two equals parts

Comment: So, in other words, the cosines of the two angles should be equal.

Comment: which two angles? i mean, how can i characterize them?